# Это надо заснять

Tags: лексика

А вот в культурной речи  в 1995 году глагол "заснять" считался профессиональным и в грамматическую систему общелитературного языка не вписывался. Но теперь им, кажется, свободно пользуются, например: "Французские кинематографисты намерены заснять спектакль".

Итак, снять кадр - заснять кадр, в чем тут разница? Каково значение приставки ЗА? Оба глагола совершенного вида, сравнить: фотографировать - сфотографировать, не "зафотографировать".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, это слово появилось во избежание путаницы со словом "снять" в некоторых контекстах (напр. снять спектакль с показа или снять его на киноплёнку). "Заснять" эквивалентно более длинному выражению "снять на плёнку (или иной носитель)", в котором однозначность смысла достигается ценой усложнения. В обычной речи тоже приходится рассуждать на эти темы, поэтому слово легко прижилось, в отличие от странно образованного термина "озвучание".

Слово "заснять" могло возникнуть по ассоциации с "зафиксировать". С одной стороны, нельзя образовать подобный глагол несовершенного вида из-за значения приставки, придающей действию законченность или результативность; с другой стороны, он не особенно  нужен: путаницы со "снимать" (напр. с репертуара) практически не возникает, поскольку "снятие" в подобных случаях - действие однократное и чаще выражается глаголом совершенного вида "снять", которому и создана альтернатива.

Comment: "Мне удалось заснять шершня, который был занят сбором коры для гнезда". Здесь выбор глагола понятен.  "Нельзя ли напрокат взять телекамеру, чтобы заснять эту великолепную поездку". "Он хочет взять у него интервью и снять на камеру". А здесь как надо говорить? Грамота.ру считает, что "заснять" - это разг. вариант, а получается, что это не совсем так. Итак, есть три варианта: снять на камеру - заснять на камеру - заснять. Получается, что надо определить область применения выражений.

Comment: Я бы отнёс к разговорным выражениям "заснять на камеру" - из-за малозаметного излишества в виде приставки. К написанию же можно отнестись с большим вниманием ("снять на камеру" или "заснять", если нужно короче).

Comment: "Я хочу снять фильм" - однозначный вариант. "Мне поручили снять/заснять сюжет для новостных роликов".  А здесь что? Какой вариант можно отнести к нейтральному стилю? И вообще, они различаются по стилю или по семантике тоже?

Comment: Здесь возможно только "снять" (сюжет, фильм), поскольку речь идёт не об объекте съёмки, а о создании кинопродукции посредством съёмки. И похоже, "заснять" больше годится для документальной съёмки (что-то происходит, и его можно заснять - как бы "подловить момент"), уж не знаю, как в профессиональной среде это слово употребляют (кажется, на площадке для постановочных съёмок говорят "снято").

Comment: Да, мне кажется, что "заснять сюжет" - это особый стиль и семантика особая. Это разовая (без повторов) съемка документального сюжета, связанного с редкими явлениями или событиями, которые представляют особый интерес. Или еще съемка событий, подобранных  по заранее заданной теме.